# Keep file highlighted after opening it from the desktop [GNOME]

Tags: desktop-environments

Since the new update I have a small problem: when I open a file from the desktop, after opening it the highlight is removed. This is somewhat problematic because when I have many similarly named files it becomes a chore to check which file I just opened. Note this only happens when I open it from the desktop, when I open it from nautilus the highlight is kept. Also, I did not have this problem before. Anyone knows where I can change this setting ? I'm using Gnome on Ubuntu 20. Many thanks.

Comment: The problem that you describe is due to the Desktop Icons GNOME Shell extension, which manages the desktop in Ubuntu 20.04. The extension does not yet have all the features that Nautilus (the former desktop manager) did. If you want, you may create a new issue in the [extension's GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/ShellExtensions/desktop-icons/-/issues?page=2&state=opened) requesting this feature. In the meantime you can use Nautilus to open your Desktop directory and manage your files.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer I'll do that.

Comment: @user3140225 maybe you should post that as an answer rather than just a comment since it's the best way to solve the problem.